# ViewPager OnTouchListener for side swipes

Tags: android, android-viewpager, xamarin, listener, ontouchlistener

In Xamarin, I have coded a `ViewPager` with an `OnTouchListener` class to prevent "side swipes" when the `ViewPager` has more that one `fragment`.

Here is my code:

```
public class OnTouchListener : Java.Lang.Object,  View.IOnTouchListener
{
    public bool OnTouch (View v, MotionEvent e)
    {
        return true;
    }
}
```

Here is the activity code:

```
OnTouchListener onTouchListener = new OnTouchListener ();
pager.SetOnTouchListener (onTouchListener);
```

This code is not working 100% correctly. Here is what I have found:

1. Normal "side swipes" are blocked such that the `ViewPager` will not change it's item when swiping horizontally.
2. However, if I make small "swipes", anywhere on one of the `ViewPager` fragments, the `ViewPager` `fragment` very slowly moves horizontally.

My question is this: How can I prevent this from happening? Is there another listener that I should use to prevent this from happening rather than the `onTouchListener`, or do I need to change my code in some way?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Have run into the same problem myself, did you ever solve it?